# Broadleaf admin - add additional tab

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I need help with the extension of the broadleaf admin panel. I want to add an additional tab in the panel displayed for a particular product. Do you know any quick way to extend this view?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new tab with `@AdminPresentation` on one of your fields the new tab will automatically appear. Example:

```
@Column(name = "SOME_COLUMN")
@AdminPresentation(friendlyName = "Some Column", tab = "New Tab Name")
private String someColumn;
```